# Как зашифровать строку, но чтобы результат был в виде цифр?

Tags: java, android

Есть строки

```
String inp_str = "A0B4FF47YG";
String key = "12345";
```

Как зашифровать строку, чтобы получились только цифры?

Пробовал "ксорить", но "вылезают" буквы.

Нужно для защиты: пользователь запускает приложение, считывается ID устройства, шифруется и сообщается разработчику. Разработчик генерирует ответный код, который сохраняется в приложении. Когда надо, приложение дешифрует сохраненный код и сравнивает.

Comment: А с чем связана необходимость чтобы были только цифры? Чем вам буквы то не угодили?

Comment: Вам же, наверно, вылезают шестнадцатеричные цифры? Вы же можете перевести их в десятичную систему?

Comment: @maestro где вы там шестнадцатеричные цифры то разглядели?

Comment: @rjhdby, в вопросе их нет, так как приведены только входные данные. Но результатом операции сложения (XOR) одного символа строки с одним символом другой строки является байт (char), который проще всего интерпретировать в шестнадцатеричном виде. А если автор вопроса кладёт этот символ в строку, то он, разумеется, получит разные буквы и нечитаемые символы.

Comment: Вы применяете какой-то алгоритм шифрования, в результате у вас получается итоговая строка, состоящая из различных символов. Замените каждый символ строковым представлением кода этого символа (то есть `'A'` -> `"65"`, `'B'` -> `"66"` и т.д.). И будет у вас в итоге строка `"65666765"`, как вы, видимо, и хотите.

Comment: @maestro ничего, что в Java строки в UTF-16?

Comment: @rjhdby, допустим. Но это ничего не меняет. Просто массив байт будет в два раза больше.

Comment: @maestro зачем тогда на шестнадцатеричные то размениваться, давайте сразу в двоичном кодировать нуль, нуль, один, чоуж

Comment: "Зачем только цифры.." - проще сообщить код, который не содержит букв.Пользователь иногда очень "странно" видит буквы. Благодарю всех за комментарии, я выяснил для себя разные полезные моменты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить каждый символ его номером.
A..Z - 00..25, 0..9 - 26..35
И склеить.